# Verifying consistency of OpenBSD LiveCD

Tags: openbsd

OpenBSD offers a live cd that can be downloaded at `http://livecd-openbsd.sourceforge.net/`

However, there is no `md5sum`, no `sha256`, no checksum of any kind on this page. How can we test this version for integrity?

Comment: Help on using SourceForge is definitely out of scope.

Comment: Clarifying @ThoriumBR's comment: SourceForge is a known malware provider, any questions should be directed at **their** support.

Answer (score 2):

OpenBSD does not require a "live" cd and if you want to err on the paranoid side you should consider creating your own "live" medium by following their own [FAQs](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq14.html#flashmemLive):

> It is very easy to create a bootable USB flash (or other!) drive that can be used as a "live" OpenBSD system without installing OpenBSD on the local hard disk of a machine. Obviously, the target machine must be bootable from a USB device, but the initial load can actually be done from any machine with a USB interface.

Benefits: if you have an OpenBSD installed you can verify the authenticity of the `bsd.rd` file by checking it against the public keys embedded in each distribution (see [this paper](http://www.openbsd.org/papers/bsdcan-signify.html) but also google for `openbsd signify`):

> After each release of OpenBSD, we generate a new key pair for the release after next. That's plus two. For example, after 5.6 was released, keys for 5.8 were generated. This way, the 5.8 keys are then included in the 5.7 release. So, if you upgrade every release, you will have an unbroken chain of keys back to your initial installation.

If you don't have an OpenBSD installed and you only want to check hardware compatibility, download (and verify!) the `bsd.rd` file, `dd` it on a portable medium, then boot it and give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

All what you have to do is to follow the [quick download link](https://sf.net/projects/livecd-openbsd/files/LiveCD-Full.iso/download) to [the projects page on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/livecd-openbsd/)

[image: MD5]

Answer (score 1):

I followed the links to download the 2 versions of what you are loooking for on SourceForge, then I canceled the download and deleted the URL until it looked like this:

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/livecd-openbsd/files/
```

Once there, you will see this:

[image]

Click on the *`i`* icon of the file that interests you and you will find what you look for:

[image]